# What is the proper way to design a comments system?

Tags: inheritance, comments

I'm implementing a site with pictures, posts, albums, etc...

Each can have a comment.

The only real difference between these comments, is that one will be a post comment, one will be an album comment, one will be a picture comment, etc...

If that's the only difference between these comments, then is it worth having sub-classes, like PostComment, AlbumComment, PictureComment which all inherit from Comment?  They all have the same fields, except the one field that distinguishes them from each other.

Is that overkill?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say there's really a 'right' way of doing it, as it depends on your specific use-case. I personally wouldn't say that a sub-class for each `PostComment`, `PictureComment` and so on is overkill, as the sub-classes would each have different fields to the main `Comment` class. Inheritance in this way would make a fine solution to the problem if you opt for classes; it clearly denotes what is unique to each sub-class and what is shared between them.

Having said that, I'd probably instead opt for a database table association, simply having a `Comments` table alongside a `Pictures` and `Posts` table. Then you can simply set up a `type` column on the `Comments` table that is a foreign key mapping out to the relevant table.

Comment: You can have one foreign key that maps to two different tables?  I've never heard of that.